# What is this ground-hugging "weed" with small purple flowers and fleshy stems?

Tags: identification, weeds, meadow

This popped up in an area that we've been converting to native meadow. I've never seen it before. We are in NY State near the beach.[image]

Comment: can you do a closer picture, or are you @That Idiot

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Storksbill (Erodium cicutarium), a member of the Geranium family. Low-growing, likes sandy soils, found in New York.

Here's a photo:
https://l7.alamy.com/zooms/ee218e16ce234c1dae7ea0a877f50dd3/storksbill-fc845f.jpg

and another:
[image]

Comment: This looks like it. But the one in my photo must have some odd conditions to grow stretched out like that.

Comment: @That Idiot - To me, the plant in the original post looks quite stressed; since the OP mentions that the meadow is near the beach, it's possible that the plant is experiencing water stress due to the (presumably) sandy soil. It could also be in too shady an area for its normal light requirements.